# Compiled. Exe on visual Studio 2017 doesn't work on Windows 2003

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have compiled a sample c++ program on VS2017 and moved the. Exe alone to Windows 2003 but there it is throwing error saying

> xyz.exe is not a valid win32 application.

Comment: You probably compiled as 64-bit

Comment: @M.M thanks for response... If you are talking about OS, I have built both 32 bit and 64 bit versions and moved both to Windows 2003 but still the same error for both. Exe files.

Comment: @user3747488 *and moved to Windows 2003* -- and how were these apps "moved"?  In that "move", you may have corrupted the executables.

Comment: Feature, not a bug, Win2003 belongs to the previous Windows generation, major version 5.  The C runtime library uses several winapi functions that are not available on such an old OS, related to threading and culture.  You have to explicitly select the "go ahead and hurt me anyway" setting.  Project > Properties > General > Platform Toolset setting, pick v141_xp.

Comment: Indeed - Server is EOL since 2015.